# .prepend is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, prepend

Please consider the following sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#btn1").click(function(){
                    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");     
                    btn.prepend("<b>Prepended text</b>. ");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <button id="btn1">Prepend text</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code throws the error in console like:

> btn.prepend is not a function

Why does this error occur? Please suggest a solution. Thank You

Comment: Please provide a link to the W3schools sample you're referencing. Google brings up nothing like that from that site.

Comment: Let us know if you got the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @squint Sorry for the inconvenience. This is not a direct code taken from the site,So i have edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, kindly do not follow the low quality articles from W3Schools. For your solution:

- The `btn` is not a jQuery object. It is a JavaScript `HTMLElement`.
- The `.prepend()` function is a jQuery function.

Your code now should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.prepend("<b>Prepended text</b>. ");
  });
});
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.prepend("<b>Prepended text</b>. ");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button id="btn1">Prepend text</button>
```

See the working snippet above. Click on the <kbd>Run Code Snippet</kbd> and click the button inside.

Comment: Thank You For the answer with snippet

Comment: @Venkat Awesome. Glad it helped you. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

The error appears because `createElement()` returns a DOMElement which does not have an `append()` method; that's only available on jQuery objects. You need to either wrap the DOMElement to a jQuery object or, better yet, create the element in jQuery:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
     var btn = $('<button />');     
     btn.prepend("<b>Prepended text</b>. ");
     // add the btn to the DOM somewhere...
});
```